# Alternative way to say "I am coming"

Tags: synonyms

Sometime, you will receive a call from a deliveryman to collect your express package in the office. I think the "wait a moment" is not a positive expression, and the "I am coming" is ambiguous to female courier. what is the alternative way to say "I am coming"?

Comment: How is "I am coming" ambiguous to a female courier? Do you mean "coming" sexually? I think context is everything here. Unless you were leering and panting, I wouldn't worry about it. And you can always say "Just a minute!"

Comment: "I have punched the 'Will attend' button."

Comment: @Robusto Yes, you got it. In the public situation, I just worried about my colleagues misunderstand my phone content :)

Comment: If you can't say "I am coming" down the phone, without invoking a *double entendre*, what in the world can you say about anything?

Answer (score 2):

> On my way!
>
> Be there in a sec!
>
> I'll be right with you. [This one is more formal and might work best in an office setting.]

Comment: Behold, I come quickly!